# How to define recursive rule for pegJS

Tags: javascript, parsing, recursion, pegjs

So, I am trying to use [PegJS](https://pegjs.org/documentation) to define a parser for a simple language.

The language consists purely of infinitely deep function calls, which are separated by commas such as:

```
f(4, g()) => [f, [4, g, []]]

g()
f(5) => [g, [], f, [5]]
```

This is the grammar i have:

```
call = 
  func"("arg")"

func =
  [a-zA-Z]+

arg =
  [0-9a-z,A-Z]+ / call


_ "whitespace"
  = [ \t\n\r]*
```

Yet its's not recursing:

input: b(r(6))

error: `Line 1, column 4: Expected ")" or [0-9a-z,A-Z] but "(" found.`

I get the idea of left vs right recursion but im not getting how to make it recurse the call rule infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your grammar ambiguity.  Expanding a little towards GNF (leading terminal), we get two rule chains for an alphabetic symbol:

arg = [0-9a-z,A-Z]+
   arg = call               # Expand call
       = func"("arg")"      # Expand func
       = [a-zA-Z]+"("arg")"

Thus, an alphabetic identifier can resolve to either an **arg** or the **func** of a **call**.  Your resulting parser apparently chose to reduce **g** to another **arg**, rather than to the first part of a **func**.

I'm not familiar with PegJS, so I can't suggest how to coerce your parser into submission.  You *do* need a 1-token lookahead to resolve this.

However, I do know about parsers in general.  Many regular expression engines are "greedy": they'll grab the longest matching string.  If you have one of these, the critical problem is that

```
arg = [0-9a-z,A-Z]+
```

will consume the span "4, g" before it returns to any other processing, thus cutting out the possibility of finding "g()" as a second argument.  In this case, what you need is a grammar that finds individual arguments, and is greedy about *each one*.  Use the comma as a separator, and put them together into an arg_list (a new non-token):

```
arg_list = arg \
           arg "," arg_list

call = func "(" arg_list ")" \
       func "()"
```

This is one canonical way to parse a function call.

Comment: Thanks! I actually solved this by making it check for a function call first before a normal argument,